# Flexbox not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

The layout I am creating isn't working in Safari though it works perfectly in Chrome. I have a feeling it has something to do with the `.wrapper` or the `.frame` but I have tried setting the Flex Shrink value to `0` to no avail.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/s6h8j1sz/)

```
.frame {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;  
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto !important;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto !important;
    flex: 1 0 auto !important;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}

.row, 
.wrapper {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

I also feel there may be a better way of using Flexbox without the need for the wrapper but can't get my head around it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is on your `.content` class. Specifically, in this section of code.

```
.content {
    display: block;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right:.5em;
  padding-bottom:.5em;
}
```

Safari still requires the `-webkit-` prefix to use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). So you will need to add the `-webkit-` prefix to you `flex` property.

### Example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdsuozxf/)):

```
.content {
    display: block;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  height: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right:.5em;
  padding-bottom:.5em;
}
```

Comment: In Safari I still have the same issue, even after adding the prefix. The .content div is shrunk down and none of the columns can be see inside of it.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1256jwn&s=8#.VP-LI_msV8E

Comment: @ChrisDance What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: I feel like you answered my question there. I don't think Flexbox works on this version of Safari and yet it's the latest version available for Windows?

Comment: @ChrisDance Yes, Apple stopped developing Safari for Windows. Safari 6 and below only support the older specification.

Comment: Unbelievable.  Safari STILL requires a prefix for an accepted CSS standard like flexbox?  When the heck are they gonna drop that vendor prefix?

Comment: FYI, Safari has been supporting flexbox without the -webkit prefix since version 9, which was released on September 30, 2015.