# Flexbox CSS not working with Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I am having class like below, which is working well on all the browser, but doesn't work with Safari.

```
.video-js .vjs-progress-control {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    order: 1;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    top: 0;
}
```

when i inspect this class in safari i can see only `top:0;` is the only element visible in safari, it's weird to me.

Comment: Try to add `position` to that(for example `position:relative;`).

Comment: which version of safari and ios?

Comment: Windows Safari - 5.1.7

Comment: Not working @alirezasafian

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex => only newest safari, 
but  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976288/flexbox-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Try adding these for older safari versions:
`display: -webkit-box;`
`display: -webkit-flex;`

Comment: No luck ;( @theStreets93. I tried it not working in none of the Safari , except IOS 9.

Comment: ..so bad.. :(  ..for modern browser use flex and make fallback for older browser, with display: inline-block.... :(

Comment: Nobody uses Safari Windows anymore except web developers for testing, you can safely forget about it. It's [4.5 years old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#Safari_5)! IE9 also from 2011 may still have a tiny marketshare and it's an order of magnitude above Saf 5.1 (Win+OS X combined, not to say what it may be on Win alone). You maybe thought you could test "Safari" on your dev environment on Windows? Not anymore, you've to test on OS X/iOS where Saf 8/9 are installed.

Comment: Ok @FelipeAls, But all these things are not working even in the IOS 5,6,7,8. only working in IOS9. When i test with Browserstack.

Answer (score 1):

Update your original code with the proper prefixes. Try this instead:

```
.video-js .vjs-progress-control {
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
            flex: 1 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -webkit-order: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
            order: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    top: 0;
}
```

Although Safari 9 supports all standard flex properties, with Safari 8 and older you'll need to use vendor prefixes.

For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [**Autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

For flexbox browser support details see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: Appriciate your answer @Michael_B, still i do not see any changes ;(

Comment: Can you post a demo (e.g., jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Hi @Michael_B, now am going with just display:block , however `-webkit-transition` , `-webkit-order` also not working

Comment: Post the HTML. If we can reproduce the problem, we can help you more.

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B , once i created a fiddle i will post here and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Try This-

```
.video-js .vjs-progress-control {
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1 1 auto;
        -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
        -webkit-order: 1;
        order: 1;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        top: 0;
    }
```